# Solspace Calendar - event_end_date not displaying in exp:calendar:cal

Tags: solspace-calendar

So I have an issue that I feel *should* be pretty simple. I'm trying to display a list of events in chronological order. On multi-day events I want to display the date in this type of format: "Month Day - Month Day" (example: April 11 - April 12.)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        {exp:calendar:cal
            {if segment_2 == ''}
                date_range_start="today"
                date_range_end="year-month-last"

            {/if}
            {if segment_2 != ""}    
                date_range_start="{segment_2}-{segment_3}-01" 
                date_range_end="{segment_2}-{segment_3}-last"
            {/if}   
        }
        {events}
            <h4 class="event-title"><a href="/events/details/{event_url_title}">{event_title}</a></h4>
            <time class="event-date">
                {if event_multi_day}
                    {event_start_date format="%F %j"} &ndash; {event_end_date format="%F %j"}
                {if:else}
                    {event_start_date format="%F %j"}
                {/if}
            </time>
            <p class="event-summary">{event_summary}</p>
        {/events}
        {/exp:calendar:cal}
```

The {event_end_date} refuses to display. I've tried this multiple ways with no success, and I'm starting to feel like I'm doing something silly and I've looked at it so long I'm just blind to the problem. Surely this variable hasn't been excluded from availability inside of calendar:cal.

If I use exp:calendar:events with that section of code to display the dates, it works perfectly.

Comment: On further exploration/testing I'm finding that on multi-day events using the exp:calendar:cal tags, {event_duration_days} is coming up as "1 day". 

This is ludicrous.

Comment: I believe we answered you in one of our support tickets on support.solspace.com (we saw the ticket before the EESE post). Have you received our reply?

Comment: I did receive the reply. I was busy this weekend so was unable to respond. I've sent additional information to you via a reply this morning. 

I posted here as well as sending you a ticket, in the hopes of someone else having solved or encountered this problem before.